# Let's hear it once again

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

If points were meals on Stack Exchange,
You'd do this, though it be strange.

It's in French when you're all viewing,
Too much boredom will be its undoing.

To check what you see, if you find me:
Pisan king, German river, instability.

---

**Edit:** Stiv has the right solution, but not the intended explanation for the last stanza. If anyone else gets this (it's quite complicated) and posts a second answer, I would upvote it.

Answer (score 8):

The general idea behind this riddle is that:

> Each stanza contains clues to words which conjure up ideas of **REPETITION** (hence the title: "*Let's hear it once again*").
>
>  (In the final 'Edit' section, I go on to propose that specifically it is the word **REPEAT** that is of interest here...)

*If points were meals on Stack Exchange,*
*You'd do this, though it be strange.*

> If 'points were meals' you would **REP EAT** ('rep' = reputation, the currency of Stack Exchange).

*It's in French when you're all viewing,*
*Too much boredom will be its undoing.*

> 'When you're all viewing' - i.e. when you're part of an audience at a show - if you wish the act to be repeated, you would all shout "**ENCORE**", a French word meaning 'again'. ('Too much boredom' would *not* result in the audience shouting this - nobody wants to sit through something tedious a second time - hence it would 'be its undoing'...)

*To check what you see, if you find me:*
*Pisan king, German river, instability.*

> There are two words hidden in this stanza. The word 'instability' clues that we are looking for *anagrams* connected to the phrases that go before it:
>
>  1. (Least sure of this one) Pisan kings of Greek mythology include Pelops and Oenomaus. Either of these could be described from their actions as an EGOMANIAC - a word which anagrams to **COME AGAIN**.
>
>  2. There are [two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oder) [rivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oder_(Harz)) called the Oder which run through or along the border of Germany - this anagrams (in fact, reverses) to **REDO**.

Later edit - a modified explanation for the overall riddle and its last stanza in particular (since my original suggestion for that part was not the OP's intent):

> In a later [comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/100503/lets-hear-it-once-again#comment291196_100585) below my answer, the OP provides a hint: "split up the word and think periodically". This way, I think we get hints towards two letters of the word at a time:
>
>  - "Pisan king" = [**Tantalus**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tantalus#Other_characters_with_the_same_name), son of Broteas. The Periodic Table symbol for the element **Tantalum** (named after a figure from Greek mythology by this name) is **Ta**.
>
>  - "German river" = The [**Rhine**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhine), after which the element **Rhenium** is named, with symbol **Re**.
>
>  - "Instability" = This may be leading us towards the scientific concept of '**[e-p instability](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0168900217312809)**'.
>
>  Adding all of these together gives us the letters **Ta**, **Re**, and **e-p**, which can be reversed when required and rearranged to form the word **Re/p-e/aT** - the word that this riddle is truly all about.
>
>  <sup>(Pleasingly, there's also a '**[Repe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repe_(river))**' river in Germany, but probably not considered major enough to have been used in this puzzle!)</sup>

Comment: You've got the right answer, and the explanation for the first two stanzas is as intended. For the last stanza, I'm very impressed that you've managed to find such a convincing alternative explanation! I can't say that it's wrong or doesn't fit, and maybe it's even better than my intended explanation of those clues (which is pretty ... indirect, maybe convoluted). Should I give you a hint about my intention for the last stanza?

Comment: @Randal'Thor I didn't think I would have the last stanza exactly right (definitely the hardest part), so a hint about intention would be useful, as my mind is now stuck on what I've already done! Thanks :)

Comment: It's only been a day, I think I'll leave it a bit longer and see if anyone else can figure out the last stanza - otherwise, will give you a hint to complete this answer :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Sounds fair. I'll see if anything else hits me...

Comment: Hint for the last line: split up the word and think periodically.

Comment: @Randal'Thor seems like Stiv got it?